# Neo4j - Complex Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j

I need to write a cypher query that finds an unknown node that has
no more than 3 edges between given 4 nodes.

For Example :
I have the nodes A,B,C,D

I need to find a node that is connected with no more than 3 edges distance from all the given nodes (A,B,C,D)

I will appreciate some help.

Thanks

Alon

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you already have some type of logic defined for how to get A,B,C,D, so I will just put ellipses in my start clause.

```
START A=..., B=..., C=..., D=...
MATCH n-[*..3]->A,
n-[*..3]->B,
n-[*..3]->C,
n-[*..3]->D
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's seems very intuitive.